# Combinatoric with different limits

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I'm looking for an algorithm for following problem:

We have N Objects that we shall distribute on C containers , while every container C has a different volume V. Now we're looking for the possible combinations to distribute the objects N on the containers C, where N has to be zero at the end. But every container can contain 0 to V objects N, depending on it's volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to solve this would be using dynamic programming: Let f(i, j) the number of ways to place the first i items into the first j containers. Let V_j be the volume of the j-th container.

Then we have the recurrence

```
f(0, 0) = 1
f(i, j) = SUM(k = 0 to min(V_j, i), f(i - k, j - 1))
```

Where k is the number of objects we place in the j-th container.

This assumes that objects are not distinguishable. If they are, you might want to multiply the result by N!.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i'm not familiar with dynamic programming. Do you have a solution for Java or some other OOP?

Comment: @Zmash Dynamic programming is a general concept which can be used in any language. Basically you set up a two-dimensional array of dimension (N+1) * (C+1). I.e. in Java: `long[][] f = new long[N+1][C+1];` and then you fill it up using a nested loop over j, i, k (the order is important so you don't access uninitialized elements)